# My Android Studio on Mac just won't let me see my files

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I open any project in android studio on mac (tried windows too), it only shows three directories: manifests, kotlin+java, and res. These are all inside of the app directory. Before the initial gradle sync of each project, I can see all the files. I have tried switching computers, switching versions, and everything else I could think of. Neither clearing cache + restarting, reinstalling or creating new projects work. The files are all still there in finder, but they simply don't show up.

I've tried restarting android studio, switching computers (mac to windows), switching ADS versions, clearing cache + restarting, reinstalling ADS and creating a new project. I was expecting more files to show up, but they are all disappeared. Image attached below.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLcJF.png)

Answer (score 1):

Above that project tree, you will find a drop-down list or spinner. Your current value there probably is "Android":

[image: Android Studio Project View Drop-Down (Highlighted with Red Arrow)]

Choose "Project" instead, and you will get a more traditional project tree:

[image: Android Studio Project View, “Project” Mode]

FWIW, I cover this in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-studiotour-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack), though the screenshots are for an older Android Studio (and not from macOS).