Why the project files disappear in Android Studio?
I cleaned up my android projects after a work shop moving projects into other directories on my Macbook.
Now, when I open the project again in Android Studio, it loads all the files as usual, but after couple of seconds they disappear and only app and gradle scrips and both are empty.

I tried to do in several ways like opening the project and importing the project into Android Studio. Both ways act the same.
What is wrong there?

I believe this is the answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/78171987/25120668
